# Navigation bar in separate html file and use it across multiple html files/pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a navigation bar that I would like to use across all the html pages of my website. I know I can use jquery to do this, but will it work if I run it locally or do I need to do it on a server?
I am using the following script to get jquery in my head tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below is the navigation bar code in the file nav.html

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li> 
<li><a href="search.html">Trailblaze</a></li>
<li><a href="Parks.html">Parks</a></li>
<li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
```

I planned on using the following js code to include it on the html pages

```
<body>
<div id="navigation"></div>
   <script>
        $.get("nav.html", function(data) {
        $("#navigation").replaceWith(data);
    });
   </script>
</body>
```

I'm not sure what the data parameters are though. I want the contents of nav.html to be where the id="navigation". Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There's an exact example in the [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

> This example fetches the requested HTML snippet and inserts it on the page.

So in your case it would be something like this (taking for granted that `#navigation` exists):

```
$.get("nav.html", function(data) {
    $("#navigation").html(data);
});
```

If working locally, Chrome **doesn't allow local Ajax requests**. Firefox does.

Comment: I used that exact code but it still didn't print the nav bar. Is it because it is a local file?

Comment: Is `nav.html` in the same directory as the `js` file making the request?

Comment: yes. I didn't use a js file for the above code though. I used script tags in an html file.

Comment: So, is the `html` file inside the same directory of `nav.html`?
Open Chrome DevTools and see if the console is outputting any error. By the way, Chrome doesn't allow local ajax requests, try on Firefox. Updated the answer.